# Get XCB connection for QWindow

Tags: qt5, x11, xcb, wgpu-rs

How do I get the XCB connection (`xcb_connection_t*`) for a given `QWindow` in Qt5?

Right now I'm using `QX11Info::connection()` to retrieve this pointer, but that depends on `libQt5X11Extras.so`, which might not be available on every target system. Alternatively, I could use `QPlatformNativeInterface::nativeResourceForWindow()` with "connection" as the first argument, but `QPlatformNativeInterface` is non-stable and might change between minor Qt releases.

Background: I'm integrating a wgpu-based renderer in a Qt application and need the native handle of the QWindow (window ID and connection pointer) to create the swapchain surface. This is working so far, but I'd like to remove the dependency on libQt5X11Extras, if possible.